# How to draw dual bottom borders on a heading?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

How can I do something like the picture below?

[image]

I would like to have an extra thick line to all my h1's but am not quite sure of a best practice to do it.

**HTML:**

```
<h1>This is Our Work</h1>
```

**CSS:**

```
h1{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #246cb4;
  display: inline-block;
}

h1:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/rjMJqV):

Comment: which part of h1 shall have a thick underline? its full width or just its center part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need any pseudo elements in this case.

You can draw multiple background images with css3 [`linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) with precisely controlled size and positions:

```
h1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #246cb4, #246cb4),
                    linear-gradient(to right, #246cb4, #246cb4);

  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 1px, 50px 3px;
  background-position: bottom 2px left, bottom 1px center;
}
```

```css
h1{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #246cb4, #246cb4),
    linear-gradient(to right, #246cb4, #246cb4);

  background-size: 100% 1px, 50px 3px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom 2px left, bottom 1px center;

  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is Our Work</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `position:relative` to the `h1` and set `margin:0 auto` to `h1:after`

```css
h1 {
   border-bottom: 1px solid #0D6CC4;
   display: inline-block;
   position:relative;
}
h1:after {
   content: "";
   display: block;
   border: 2px solid #0D6CC4;
   width: 50px;
   margin-top: 0px;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   left:0 ;
   bottom:-2px;
   margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is Our Work</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

used this css

```
h1:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: -3px;
}
h1 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #246cb4;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this just with a few tweaks in styling related to `position`.

```css
h1{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #246cb4;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

 h1:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: -1.5px;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is Our Work</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to position element `:after` and `:before`

```css
 .main-title{
   text-align: center;
   }
.inner-title{
position: relative;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 0 0 15px;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;  
}

h1:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 150px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -75px;
    height: 1px;
    background: blue;
    bottom: 0;
}
h1:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25px;
    height: 3px;
    background: blue;
    bottom: -1px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="main-title" >
  <h1 class="inner-title">Sevices</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know how long every `h1` tag will be, i suggest you to translate the element to the center of its parent, like in this example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jyMzqN

```
h1 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #246cb4;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

 h1:after {
   content: "";
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   height: 3px;
   background-color: black;
   width: 50px;
   left: 50%;
   bottom: -2px;
   transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```